# What is the official name for Microsoft Metro Design?

Tags: user-interface, microsoft-metro

What is the official name for Microsoft Metro Design?

- Metro Design
- Metro style design
- Microsoft design style
- Microsoft design
- Modern Design
- Microsoft Modern Design
- Microsoft Design Language
- Microsoft UI design

Comment: I think it's `Windows Store App Design` as many MSDN docs describe like that.

Answer (score 0):

[Sorry, Microsoft, the Experts Have Spoken: Windows 8’s Interface Is Called Metro](http://techland.time.com/2013/06/30/sorry-microsoft-the-experts-have-spoken-windows-8s-interface-is-called-metro/) from Time Tech